# PHP Grid recommendations needed

Tags: php, gridview

I'm looking for a grid control for a project I'm doing in PHP.

Are there any good recommendations?

Ideally, it'd have a data entry mode similar to a spreadsheet where the user could enter row after row after row, without needing to click new/edit buttons or links.

Comment: Database driven? Just a session? There isn't a lot of information here about the question IMHO

Comment: Urda, 

  Database driven would be great, I didn't want to make the question too wordy..

  I guess I am just looking for some direction as to which control(s) are good and the best approach towards them.  I've seen extjs recommended a few times, but given it's a javascript grid, I wondered if there was an easier way to deal with all the backend php stuff.

Answer (score 7):

You might want to take a look at [KoolGrid](http://www.koolphp.net/?mod=products&act=view&id=11) and [phpGrid](http://www.phpgrid.com/grid/)

Both are very powerful and similarly priced.

...

Another Free Alternate is [JQgrid PHP Component](http://azgtech.wordpress.com/2010/08/01/jqgrid-php-datagrid/)

Comment: IMO, phpGrid is your best bet if you don't want to spend too much fiddling tedious CRUD operations yourself. It literally takes care all the DB operations for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use [ExtJS](http://www.extjs.com/) for your front-end ([editable grid demo](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/grid/edit-grid.html)), and PHP scripts to do the actual data processing. You won't regret it :p.

BTW It is not cheap for commercial use (ie. when you want to distribute your application - you don't need a commercial license if your app is for internal/intranet use only), but imho it's money well spent.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to have a simple PHP script that is called via ajax. That way the user can continually enter data into cells while it is saved in the background, and the user won't have to reload the page.

Comment: Are there any grids that would work with this very simply?

I am assuming I could do this with extjs if I had enough time to spend, unfortunately, I am looking for the quick route on this one for the moment.

Comment: I'm not sure on that one, you might try looking at some of the Google Libraries, but I'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

php is just for backend processing and javascript will do the rest .
there are ton of jquery plugin that ease this mission 
i love to use [flexigrid](http://flexigrid.info/)

and here is some of them http://www.webdesignbooth.com/15-great-jquery-plugins-for-better-table-manipulation/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Great link to the sites!

Answer (score 0):

I personally use SDTable. It's straight-forward and pretty fast.
[SDTable downloads](http://www.sdtable.com/downloads)